# Unity Game Preview Far Too Pixelated, Aspect Ratio Options Missing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, aspect-ratio, build-settings

I am developing an Android/iOS application which will always be viewed in the "horizontal left" orientation. Originally I was developing on Unity 2019.2.9f1, but switched to 2019.2.14f1 when I encountered this issue. Sadly it is present on both engine versions.

I am using a world space canvas, and previously it was displaying and building fine for all aspect ratios. Previously I had over a dozen aspect ratio options, which you can see here:

[image]

However, they have recently all vanished, leaving only these:

[image]

When I select Free Aspect, the scene is visible as seen below, which is correct:

[image]

However, when I try and display on the desired "PhoneHorizontal" aspect ratio, you can see that it is extremely zoomed in and pixelated. When I zoom out to 1x instead of 52x, the scene is obviously extremely small.

[image]

Could it be that something in my project settings that is causing this? I thought the engine itself was bugged, but reinstalling a new version did not fix it. I do not know what originally led to this change. I have looked at my build settings and my players settings and they all seem fine. There is nothing in my code that affects the aspect ratio or display settings.

Edit: I have confirmed that this problem only exists when the platform is set to Android. This issue is not present for iOS. In addition, it is only present in the editor, not when I build to my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot. You are setting the resolution of *GameView* to **16x10** not the aspect ratio. You can check that in format how is that displayed.

Aspect ration uses **:**
Resolution uses  **x**

So
**16:9** is an aspect ratio
**16x9** is a resolution of GameView

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I missed that! In hindsight that makes a lot of sense. Thank you, this has solved the problem.